# CTE и обновление данных

Tags: postgresql

Почему при выполнении данного запроса в таблицу table2 вставляется запись с table1 со значение до обновления в CTE? Ведь транзакция одна и планировщик показывает что сначала выполняется обновление данных.

до: table1(id=1, name='Bob')

```
with cte as (update table1 set name = 'John' where id = 1) insert into table2 select * from table1 where id = 1;
```

после: table1(id=1, name='John'), table2(id=1, name='Bob')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [задокументировано](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other
> and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
> statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
> happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same
> *snapshot* (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects
> on the target tables.

Все меняющие данные части CTE оперируют одним и тем же снимком видимости.

Чтобы оперировать результатом запроса, используйте RETURNING и обращайтесь к данным этого запроса

```
with cte as (
  update table1 set name = 'John' where id = 1
  returning *
) 
insert into table2 select * from cte;
```